# Anyway to get div with position:absolute outside of div with position:relative?

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div>
      <div class="c">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a { position:relative; }
.b { position:absolute; }
```

I understand that defining top and left/right properties positions absolute div to either its parent with position:relative or to the browsers window if such a parent doesn't exist. What I'm faced with, I cannot change the CSS for .a and .b. And I need .c to be on top of .a and slightly out of it. So that .a doesn't get a scroll bar.

Some ASCII art to illustrate, I guess :)

I have:

```
-------------------
|   .a           |^|
|                | |<-- Scroll bar
|   ------       | |
|   | .c |       |*|
-------------------
```

I need:

```
--------------------
|   .a             |
|                  |<-- No scroll bar
|   ------         |
|   | .c |         |
----|    | ---------
    |    |
    ------
```

Comment: Just position `.c` absolutely.

Comment: Hold on... If you can change the CSS for `.c`, why can't you change the CSS for `.a` and `.b`? Otherwise, it'd be as simple as specifying `overflow:hidden` on `.a` and `.b`.

Comment: no, since it will always be either relative or absolute to its parent container. you could due, apply a higher values then the container, and make the parent have an overflow:hidden.

Comment: Šime Vidas - if I do position:absolute on .c, it will not get out of .a, since .a is positioned relatively.

Comment: wecsam - This is a crazy pop-up menu that I'm dealing with designed originaly by third party people. For this release, business wants a nested menu inside of a nested menu... I could change CSS for .a and .b, but that might mess up the whole existing structure.

Comment: Dementic - what do you mean by "higher values"? I played with z-index, that doesn't do anything for as long as .a is positioned relatively.

Comment: @Dimskiy Sure it will: http://jsfiddle.net/rbT6u/

Comment: Šime Vidas - Thank you! It's the overflow-y:auto that I have defined for .b that messes up everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution will stack all items and the `<div class="c">` will reach out of its parent container:

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #eee;
}
        
.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #ccc;
}
        
.c {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div>
      CONTENT
      <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note** that this will only work, if the parent container has `overflow:visible`. When one of the parents has `overflow:hidden|scroll` you can't solve this, I guess.

Comment: It's the overflow-y:scroll on .b that I have completely missed up until posting this question. Thank you, this answer is correct.